# Twitter Bootstrap on page tabs: not hiding tab content

Tags: jquery, tabs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the twitter on page tabbed content to work. I have the tabs working with switching around active class on the tabs. I've included jquery and the bootstrap-tabs.js but the following code can't seem to get the tabbed content to hide / display as they should. Any help on what may be a simple fix would be appreciated.

```
<div class="span8">
        <ul class="tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#2009">2009</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2010">2010</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2011">2011</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="pill-content">
            <div class="active" id="2009">
                2009 copy
            </div>
            <div id="2010">
                2010 copy
            </div>
            <div id="2011">
                2011 copy
            </div>

        </div>
        <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.tabs').tabs()
        })
        </script>
    </div><!-- end span 8 -->
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS? If the classes are being added successfully, chances are your error is in your CSS.

Comment: ah you were right. I figured out I needed to set a class to the pill-content divs with a display of none, and then as the javascript switches the classes to active in the css to display block. I thought something was already in place for that int he css, but I got it working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bootstrap example is incomplete - you need class="pill-pane" (or maybe tab-pane) on the tab elements with the ids

```
<div class="span8">
    <ul class="tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#2009">2009</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2010">2010</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2011">2011</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="pill-content">
        <div class="active pill-pane" id="2009">
            2009 copy
        </div>
        <div class="pill-pane" id="2010">
            2010 copy
        </div>
        <div class="pill-pane" id="2011">
            2011 copy
        </div>

    </div>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('.tabs').tabs()
    })
    </script>
</div><!-- end span 8 -->
```

Comment: In my case, I was missing the class="tab-content" on the parent element.

Comment: class="tab-content" is the issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the class on the content to class="tab-content" then I think the display:none would work correctly and no need for an inline style.